# Chrome not displaying regional language

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

My chrome is not able to display my regional language like Hindi.

But I can see that page properly in Safari.

- **Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

- **Safari:**

[image]

**I am using:**

- iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)
- MacOS Sierra (10.12.2)
- Chrome version : 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)

It was working properly few week ago. 
I think some Sierra OS update make this change but I am not sure about this. I try to find the solution online, follow some steps and download some font but nothing still works.

If anyone has faced this kind of problem and solve I will like tp try that solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try going to Applications > Font Book and doing File > Restore Standard Fonts and restarting.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks. I have tried as you say but still no effect after restart mac.